# Rails check if params values are set without knowing the keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails

all,

I got this request:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>{"name_equals"=>"", "age_equals"=>""}}
```

What I want to check is, if `name_equals` or `age_equals` have got a value set, just by knowing 
params[:search]. There can be more values in `search` than in the example.

I hope someone can help me with this, thanks.

-e-
you are all a bit right, know i go with:

```
blank = params[:search].values.all?(&:blank?) if params[:search] != nil
@search = BillingDestination.search(blank ? nil : params[:search])
```

a combination between Tass and Łukasz Niemier answers ;) Tass forgot the .values and Lukasz the & sign.

How could i do this on one line?

Comment: Iterate over the hash keys and check?

Comment: params[:search].each_value {|value| blank = value.blank? }, so blank should be false if there is a value, right?

Answer (score 2):

Go with

```
params['search'].values.any?(&:blank?)
```

Comment: IMHO nicer will be `params[:search].any?(&:blank?)`

Answer (score 1):

Just check if all the values are present.

```
params[:search].all? { |k, v| v.present? }
```

For the sake of it you could just check the values as well

```
params[:search].values.all?(&:present?)
```

Missed the & sign indeed.

Comment: with a &-sign it works: params[:search].values.all?(&:present?)

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
if params['search'] && (params['search']['name_equals'] && params['search']['name_equals'])
# do something
end
```

with:

```
 # get all keys
 all_the_keys = params['search'].keys 

 # or if you only want ones that contain something
 all_the_non_blank_keys = params['search'].select {|k,v| !v.blank?}
```

Comment: But i don't know the keys from params['search']

Comment: only that that there is a search hash?

Comment: exactly, i just know search